# Numeric validation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, numeric

To validate that the input field contains a numeric value I'm using the isNumeric() method of jQuery:

```
$.isNumeric(value);
```

This works fine for most of the cases, but the following example fails:

```
$.isNumeric("0.");
```

This returns true while it's not a numeric value.

Is there a better way of such validation without using any other plugin?

Thanks.

Comment: `The argument can be of any type.` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isnumeric/

Comment: It's likely parsing it

Comment: Do you want decimals too or just ints?

Comment: Decimals and integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't listed all of your use cases, but I have ran through a couple in the console, including your breaking case;

You can simply cast the string to a JavaScript Number:

```
$.isNumeric(Number("0."))
=> true
```

And it seems to work with strings that aren't numbers as well.

```
$.isNumeric(Number("fasd"))
=> false
```

AMEND:

```
$.isNumeric(Number(0.))
=> true

$.isNumeric(Number(.0))
=> true
```

Also, if your DB doesn't like "0." then cast the thing:

```
Number(0.)
=> 0

Number(.0)
=> 0

Number(".0")
=> 0

Number("0.")
=> 0
```

Let me know if this solution doesn't cover your problem. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't. The data structure I'm storing the values in won't accept "0." or ".0" as valid numeric types so I want to prevent that.

Comment: Your question seems to ask how to query a string for Numeric status.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Example:

```
var matches = val.match(/\d+/g);
if (matches != null) {
    alert('number');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to check the type, you can use [jQuery.type()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.type/):

```
console.log(jQuery.type( "0." ) === "number");// False
console.log(jQuery.type( 0. ) === "number");// True
```

Just for completeness, using this approach of type, you could check numbers this way:

```
var isNumber = function(o) {
    return typeof o === 'number' && isFinite(o);
}
```

BTW, `0.` and `.0` are valid number formats in javascript.

Comment: Nah, I'm looking for a generic way to validate numeric values - integers and decimals.

Comment: The data structure I'm storing the values in won't accept "0." or ".0" as valid numeric types so I want to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my solution:

```
!$.isNumeric(value) || value.substring(value.length - 1) == "." || value.substring(0, 1) == "."
```

If the result of this is false - the value is not numeric including 5. and .5 which are valid numeric values in JavaScript.

Thanks everybody for your input.